# Why are "dynamic" and "deontic" modalities so called?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology, modality

It is said that there are three types of modality: deontic, epistemic and dynamic.

Here are sample sentences for each type of modality:

> (1) *You **can** stay as long as you want.* [deontic]
>
> (2) *You **may** be right.* [epistemic]
>
> (3) *He **can** drive better than you.* [dynamic]

The first two names are said to be derived from the Greek for "biding" and "knowledge", respectively.

As far as 'epistemic' is concerned, the meaning derived from the Greek is such that I can easily understand why linguists who coined these terms did so.

As for 'dynamic' and 'deontic', however, it's not as clear to me why 'dynamic' and 'deontic' are chosen to coin the term 'dynamic modality' and 'deontic modality', respectively.

Specifically, what's so 'dynamic' about sentence (3)? (3) represents the subject's ability. I mean, what has being 'dynamic' got to do with anything about the subject's ability?

And what's so 'deontic' about sentence (1)? (1) represents the speaker's permission, and not any sort of 'duty' as expressed by the word 'deontic'.

Hence these question:

**What's the specific meaning of 'dynamic' in 'dynamic modality' that is descriptive of this type of modality?**

**Why use the difficult word 'deontic' when it doesn't actually represent the whole picture of the type of modality that it's supposed to represent?**

Comment: dynamic modality: "the conditioning factors are internal – the subject's own ability or willingness to act" WP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_modality

Comment: For more details on modalities: http://dinamico2.unibg.it/anglistica/slin/modgloss.htm PDF! -> http://www.skase.sk/Volumes/JTL09/pdf_doc/4.pdf

Comment: This question might be better asked at [Linguistics.se].

Answer (score 7):

The expression *deontic* is derived from the Greek *deomai* (δέομαι), translated *request*:

> (1) *You **can** stay as long as you want*, implies ***permission***.

The expression *epistemic* is derived from the Greek *epistamai* (ἐπίσταμαι), translated *to know*:

> (2) *You **may** be right*, implies supporting ***knowledge***.

The expression *dynamic* is derived from the Greek *dunamai* (δύναμαι), translated *to be able*:

> (3) *He **can** drive better than you*, implies ***ability***.

---

Linguists, like lawyers, doctors and many other professionals, employ obscure terminology from ancient languages so that they can control their definitions without interference from colloquial semantic pressures. The confusion surrounding *dynamic* seems to arise from a modern colloquial connotation which irrelevant to the modality descriptor:

> adjective
>
> 1 (Of a process or system) characterized by constant change, activity,
>   or progress:
>   *ODO*
>
> [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dynamic&allowed_in_frame=0):
>
> 1817 as a term in philosophy; 1827 in the sense "pertaining to force
>   producing motion" (the opposite of static),
>   from French dynamique
>   introduced by German mathematician Gottfried Leibnitz (1646-1716) in
>   1691 from Greek dynamikos "powerful,"
>   from dynamis "power," from dynasthai "to be able, to have power, be strong enough," which is of
>   unknown origin.
>   The figurative sense of "active, potent, energetic"
>   is from 1856 (in Emerson). Related: Dynamically.
>   *etymonline.com*

Comment: *You may be right* **may** imply more of the ***lack*** of supporting knowledge ;-)